# Где ошибка в селекторе jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('document').ready(function() { // Не работает
    $("a[href^=http://]").attr("target", "_blank");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Вот, что выдает консоль JavaScript в браузере Google Chrome **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href^=http://] jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').attr("target", "_blank");
```